# Why the charater "%" is printed after performing a printf without "\n"?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, printf

Here is my simple c code. Can anyone tell me why it gives me this output?
I am coding on an arch linux 4.15.1-2-ARCH machine with the gcc compiler (version: 7.3.0)
I compile with: gcc --std=c99 -Wall --pedantic client.c -o client

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("Test.");
  return 0;
}
```

But it get the following Output:
    `Test.%`

I don't know where the % is comming from. Would be great if someone can give me a hint.

Comment: Is your shell prompt `%`?

Comment: and it's not the prompt from your shell?

Comment: To clarify: I get a different result. `Test.~/Documents $`. (Blinky thing after the `$` left out because I cannot enter that in a comment.)

Comment: no thats not my shell prompt. If i execute the printf command like that: printf("Test. \n");
Than there is no such %

Comment: Screenshot perhaps?

Comment: This is a classic facepalm moment

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362772/what-is-percent-sign-prompt-in-a-shell

Comment: @Barmar, yeah but why do i have to print a newline at the end? And do you have an idea how i can fix this, if i not want to do a \n every time i use the printf funktion?

Comment: @Philluminati `puts("Test.");`

Comment: @Philluminati why wouldn't you want to do a \n every time? That's pretty standard.

Comment: If no proof is coming, VTCing as non-reproducible.

Comment: @ArthurDent oh okay, i didn't know that this is more or less standard. Since now i was coding with a visual studio on a windows machine. And there were no such results when i left the \n out.

Comment: @Philluminati To be clear, it's standard when you want your output to be on its own line.

Comment: @Philluminati [no thats not my shell prompt.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48796875/programm-is-printing-the-charater-after-performing-a-printf-command#comment84596233_48796875) --> What character(s) is your shell prompt?

Comment: i am using zsh, so a "➜" and then the folder

Comment: I suspect the `%` may be a indication (from the shell) that the last output of the program did not in with a `'\n'`.

Comment: Then I don't understand why did you accept the answer below.

Comment: Here is the answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167582/why-zsh-ends-a-line-with-a-highlighted-percent-symbol Just curious what you get if running it under root.

Comment: yeah i mean, it solved my problem but i still don't know where the % is comming from

Comment: @EugeneSh. Good find.  I was [close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48796875/programm-is-printing-the-charater-after-performing-a-printf-command#comment84596592_48796875).

Comment: thank you for that link, that explains it pretty much. But i think i am not able to accept a comment as an answer, or is that possible somehow?

Comment: You can write an answer yourself, if you wish and accept it. But since there is already a comprehensive answer on SE anyway, I don't think it is a good idea.

Comment: @EugeneSh. If I execute the prgramm as root, the output is without %

Comment: @EugeneSh. Okay anyway, thank you for that answer!

Comment: @Philluminati Root probably doesn't use `zsh` as its shell.

Comment: Please show your code and screen capture of the output since you claim it is not a shell prompt. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 2):

Your `printf` string doesn't contain a newline character.  As a result, whatever string your shell normally prints as a prompt will appear immediately after what your program prints.

Running on my machine:

```
$ ./x1
Test.$
```

My prompt is "$", so that's what appears after the string

Adding `\n`, which is the escape sequence for a newline, to your string will make your prompt appear on the following line:

```
printf("Test.\n");
```

Output:

```
$ ./x1
Test.
$
```

Comment: He said it's not his shell prompt.

Comment: Werther or not his shell prompt, the problem seems completely outside of OP's program.

Comment: so i have to write \n every time i use the printf command? Or is there another opertunity to solve this?

Comment: @Philluminati: no, you only need to write `\n` when you want the cursor put at the start of a new line. That does not mean "every time". Your program cannot *guess* when you want a new line and when you don't.

Comment: @Philluminati If you don't want whatever text you print next to be on the same line, then yes it needs to be added.  Depending on what you're printing, you might not necessarily want a newline printed.

Comment: ...or when you must have the output sent when debugging.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I use `stderr` for that – it seems to me that automatically flushes as well.

Comment: @Philluminati, just follow this phrase _Computers don't do what you want, they only do what you say_  (even if it's wrong) so, if you want a new line, you have to say _I want it!!!_  From my point of view, `\n` is not a great penalty.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
printf("Test.\n");
```

The word `Test.` printed by your program probably joined with the first character of your terminal prompt. Adding a `\n` will print a new line character, so your terminal prompt will be written on the next line when your program exits.